# Determining the points of intersection of a parametric line with the coordinate planes

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

> Find the points where the line given by $x = 7t + 9$, $y = 8t - 7$, and $z = -7t - 2$ intersect the $xy$, $xz$, and $yz$ planes.

*Attempted solution:*

This seems as though a very simple problem to me. Take, for example, finding the intersection with the $xz$ plane. It must be that $y = 0$. I substitute $y = 0$ to obtain $t = \frac{7}{8}$, then $x = \frac{121}{8}$ and $z = -\frac{65}{8}$. The point of intersection is $(\frac{121}{8}, 0, -\frac{65}{8})$.

It seems, however, that my solution is wrong, which completely baffles me.

What is the correct approach?

Comment: That is the correct approach. Why do you think it’s wrong?

Comment: @tomi I've been informed that this solution, and several other solutions using the same approach, are wrong, which really had be banging my head against a wall, as I don't see where I could possible have gone wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the points where the line given by $x = 7t + 9$, $y = 8t - 7$, and $z = -7t - 2$ intersect the $xy$, $xz$, and $yz$ planes.
Your approach is correct, You can also write the equation of line in symmetric form:

$$\frac{x-9}7=\frac{y+7}8=\frac{z+2}{-7}$$

Now intersection of this line with xy, yz and zx is respectively :

xy): $z=0\Rightarrow x-9=-2\Rightarrow x=7, y+7=-\frac{16}7\Rightarrow y=-\frac{65}7$

YZ): $x=0$

zx): $y=0$